# ./configure is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: xcode, github, github-for-windows, libsodium

I am trying to use this github code in github shell, but the message

> ./configure is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

```
$ git clone git@github.com:jedisct1/libsodium.git
    $ ( cd libsodium && \
    ./configure --prefix="/usr/local" --disable-ssp --disable-pie \
                    --disable-silent-rules && \
    make && make check && sudo make install && make clean )
```

what to do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Check out do you have installed [autogen], [autoconf] and [libtool] packages.

Answer (score 1):

I had same error while I was trying to figure out how to compile htmlcxx on Windows using MinGW
and running

```
autoreconf -i`
```

before "./configure" helped me with this issue.